# \selectlanguage does not change itemize style

Tags: itemize, babel, french

I have some trouble with the LaTeX `babel` package. As you may know, depending on the language, say `french` or `english`, it is a normal fact that `itemize` lists are not displayed in the same style (French style is more compact and uses dashes instead of bullets). For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
Blah. Blah blah!
\begin{itemize}
\item Item;
\item Other item.
\end{itemize}
To be continued\dots
\end{document}
```

yields

[image: English-style typesetting]

while replacing `english` by `french`, we would get

[image: French-style typesetting]

Fine. But now, suppose that I have loaded both languages for `babel`, with `english` loaded last, and that I want to get French typography thanks to the `\selectlanguage` command, i.e. that I write the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{french}
Blah. Blah blah!
\begin{itemize}
\item Item;
\item Other item.
\end{itemize}
To be continued\dots
\end{document}
```

Then, I expect to get the same result as just before. But this is not the case actually: though things work fine as regards spacing before exclamation marks and semicolons or after points, the itemize style remains like in English!

[image: Itemize problem]

What is the explanation for that fact? (Is it a bug in the `babel` package?...). And of course, has anyone a nice solution (*) to avoid this nasty behaviour?

(*) Of course, I could make a hack inside my `itemize` environment to force the French itemize style (resp. the English itemize style after `\selectlanguage{english}`); but my goal is to get everything okay with the single `\selectlanguage{...}` command... (Also, I would like to get a solution which is directly portable with any languages).

P.S.: Actually my goal is to write a package allowing for several languages, with slightly different behaviours depending on the language wished by the user. So, I have to load all the possible languages when writing `\RequirePackage[...]{babel}`, and then use `\selectlanguage`... But then I have the problem explained above, and this much annoys me! :-(

Comment: I think the behaviour you observe is the correct one; it will be more distracting to have different itemize conventions in one document than having a "foreign" itemize convention on pieces of text in another language.

Comment: @jknappen: Indeed, this is the explanation given by frenchb.dtx (thanks to jfbu for having pointed out that documentation to me). But actually my motivation was to write a package so that I would select one sole language for all the document, but that language being given as an option of my package. Therefore, I would have to load `babel` with both options `french` and `english` first, and then only to choose the document main language. But `babel` package does not allow for that: it must be loaded (with selecting the main language) once for all... :-(

Comment: For this purpose, the answer is simple: Delay the loading of the babel package until you know all the options of your package. Than load the babel package with the options determined from the evaluation of your package's options.

Comment: @jknappen: You are right indeed! I mistakenly believed that it was mandatory to put the `\RequirePackage` commands *before* processing the package options, because I was relying on a tutorial (http://www.tuteurs.ens.fr/logiciels/latex/nouveau_package.html#s3_1) which at some point suggested that it was the case... (Anyway, it is good to know that `\selectlanguage{french}` command does not set on *all* the features of the French language! ;-)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> Starting with version 2.2a, frenchb alters the layout of lists,
>   footnotes, and the indentation of first paragraphs of sections) only
>   if French is the “main language” [...]  otherwise frenchb doesn’t
>   change anything regarding lists, footnotes, and indentation of
>   paragraphs.

And it also says that if French is the main language, then the layout of lists is modified *in all languages*.

Global package options (to be set with `\frenchbsetup`) are provided:

1. `StandardLayout=true` forces frenchb, in case French is the main language, not to modify layout of lists.
2. `GlobalLayoutFrench=false` has the effect, in case French is the main language, to apply modification to lists *only* in parts of the document using French.

`\frenchbsetup` is (as very often the case in LaTeX style with the "premable" idea which is arguably not such a good idea and makes it very difficult to mix distinct documents; also because there is no "undo this loading of package foo" available) a `preamble-only` command.

I do not see in the documentation commands to toggle customization of lists mid-way in the document, probably some inner commands are available but I did not check. Thus, it seems you should select `french` as main language (last loaded option for `babel`), and possibly `2.` above depending how you want lists to look in parts of the document in other languages.

Comment: Wonderful answer; many thanks jbfu! 8-D